# How to update Sequelize Model excluding fields

Tags: sequelize.js

Looking at Sequelize docs, I find how to specify what fields I want to update, but I want specify what fields I **don't** want to update.

Something like that:
`Model.update(,{excludeFields:['id']})`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Get all your fields and then exclude the ones you don't want.

```
const fieldsToExclude = ['password', 'sensitive_info', 'attribute_not_allowed_due_to_user_role']    
const myFields = Object.keys(MyModel.rawAttributes).filter( s => !fildsToExclude.includes(s))
MyModel.update(newValue, {fields: myFields})
```

If you are asking (and you should) where did I get this, it is not in the doc! 
continue reading.

**Some Details**
While I really like Sequelize, I admit that their Reference lacks some info sometimes.

e.g. The fact that `findByPk` internally calls `findOne` which internally calls `findAll`, that means the `options` object passed to `findAll` also applied to `findOne` and `findByPk`

Unfortunately, `update` method doesn't handle `options` object same as `find*` family of functions.
Below is how `update` handle `fields` attribute of `options` object

```
// Remove values that are not in the options.fields
    if (options.fields && options.fields instanceof Array) {
      for (const key of Object.keys(values)) {
        if (options.fields.indexOf(key) < 0) {
          delete values[key];
        }
      }
    } else {
      const updatedAtAttr = this._timestampAttributes.updatedAt;
      options.fields = _.intersection(Object.keys(values), Object.keys(this.tableAttributes));
      if (updatedAtAttr && options.fields.indexOf(updatedAtAttr) === -1) {
        options.fields.push(updatedAtAttr);
      }
    }
```

On the other hand, `find*` function will eventually go through `_.confirmOptions()` which will call `_expandAttributes()`, implemented as follows:

```
  static _expandAttributes(options) {
    if (_.isPlainObject(options.attributes)) {
      let attributes = Object.keys(this.rawAttributes);

      if (options.attributes.exclude) {
        attributes = attributes.filter(elem => {
          return options.attributes.exclude.indexOf(elem) === -1;
        });
      }
      if (options.attributes.include) {
        attributes = attributes.concat(options.attributes.include);
      }

      options.attributes = attributes;
    }
  }
```

That's where the "exclude" logic happens.

*HTH*

Comment: I needed this behavior in a `beforeUpdate` hook and since you only have the instance in the hook, setting field to be excluded to `undefined` had the effect of excluding it.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this problem, I did not find an way for resolve this in sequelize docs, but I resolved it with something like this:

```
Model.findOne()
  .then(instance => {
    const fields = instance.attributes.filter(attribute => {
      return !['foo'].includes(attribute);
    });

    return instance.update(data, { fields });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of attributes you want to exclude is small like 2 or one and if you want just to not allow a certain attribute to be updated, the simplest solution is delete the object attribute from the object of change.

```
if (model) {
  delete model.password;
  delete model.sensitive_info;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works for update as well?

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: { exclude: ['baz'] }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not correct. While that works for `findAll`, that won't work for `update`